# Graphing a P-P plot given a set of data from a Poisson distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm attemping to complete an assignment for a class and reading the book isn't particularly helpful as it's extremely wordy and unclear.  I'm mainly confused on exactly what the x and y values are supposed to be within a P-P plot.  The problem I'm given is as follows:

> If the following data are hypothesized to be drawn from a Poisson
>   distribution:
>
> 3, 0, 7, 2, 6, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 0 0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 3, 4, 4, 7, 2, 3, 6
>   2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 0, 3, 4, 3, 5
>
> Draw a P-P plot for the distribution.

The book states something along the lines of:

> A probability–probability (P–P) plot is a graph of the model
>   probability $Fˆ(X_{(i)})$ versus the sample probability
>   $F˜_{n}(X_{(i)}) = q_i,$ for i = 1,2,...,n

Based on earlier assignments, it's my understanding that $F˜_{n}(X_{(i)}) = \frac{i-0.5}{n}$, but what is the formula for $Fˆ(X_{(i)})$? And which belongs on which axis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Comment:**

The notation is unfamiliar, and I confess I have never tried this for a
Poisson sample before. So I am less than 100% sure this is going to give
you what the author of your 'not particularly helpful' text intended.

The points $q_i = (i-.5)/n$ for $i = 1, \dots, n$ are intended to be evenly spread points between 0 and 1. The choice of axes for
similar plots of normal data seems to depend on country. In the US I have
most often seen 'data points' on the horizontal axis.

Here is what I tried in R, and the resulting graph. (In R `ppois` is the Poisson CDF.)

```
x=c(3, 0, 7, 2, 6, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 3, 
    4, 4, 7, 2, 3, 6, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 0, 3, 4, 3, 5)
q = (1:length(x)-.5)/length(x)
F = ppois(sort(x), mean(x))
plot(F, q, pch=19)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks regardless Bruce, I ended up graphing something similar (Though my points appear to stretch horizontally versus vertically) - I probably didn't calculate the Poisson CDF properly.  I'll go ahead and mark this as correct, simply to close the question - when I get back to class and ask the teacher about it, I'll update you with what I've been told!